# Masonry ImagesLoaded HTML5 Video Poster

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry, imagesloaded

I'm using [masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/) along with the [imagesloaded.pkgd.js](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/) plugin. The ImagesLoaded script is supposed to detect when the browser has finished loading images before initialising masonry.

Whilst this works with images in img tags it doesn't work with [HTML5 Video's poster tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp).

Is there a way to get ImagesLoaded to play nice with the HTML5 Video Poster attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised the issue on imagesLoaded's git repo. According to the author, the library doesn't support HTML5 video poster loading but it has been logged as a feature request.

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/197

I decided to use [jQuery's Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method which has a callback that fires after the element has loaded. Since I wanted to fire a single callback after all images were loaded I just included a counter.

```
var posterCount = $('video').length;
var postersLoaded = 0;

$('video').load(function () {

    postersLoaded++;

    if (postersLoaded >= posterCount) {


        $('#contentList').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.csContent'
        });

        $('#contentList').masonry('reloadItems');
        $('#contentList').masonry('layout');

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

After each video I add an `<img>` tag with the poster source and `display: none`. Seems to work without issues. Also as I would hope; chrome dev tools reports the image is only loaded once.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this, in the newer version of jquery

```
$('video').on('loadeddata',function (){

postersLoaded++;

if (postersLoaded >= posterCount) {


    $('#contentList').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.csContent'
    });

    $('#contentList').masonry('reloadItems');
    $('#contentList').masonry('layout');

}
```

});

secondly one might run into issues of the videos being cached. check out this link
https://dev.opera.com/articles/consistent-event-firing-with-html5-video/